# Case when in group by in R

Tags: r

I want to perform a sumif equivalent operation in R .

Whenever the ID and type match and the flag is 0, I want to calculate a percentage (in the below example , it is (1/(9+30826)) else I want to keep it as 0% (when there is no 0 flag)

Here is the example :

```
ID  Type    Flag  Value1  Value2 
1   Apple   0        1     9        
1   Apple   1     29312    30826  
1   Orange  1     2222     3423
2   Orange  1     24566    32234
```

I want the following result :

```
ID  Type    Value1  Value2  Result
1   Apple   29313   30835   0.0032%
1   Orange  2222    3423    0%
2   Orange  24566   32234   0%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ave()`:

```
d <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="ID  Type    Flag  Value1  Value2 
1   Apple   0        1     9        
1   Apple   1     29312    30826  
1   Orange  1     2222     3423
2   Orange  1     24566    32234")

d$Result <- ave(ifelse(d$Flag==0, d$Value1, 0), d$ID, d$Type, FUN=sum) / ave(d$Value2, d$ID, d$Type, FUN=sum) 
d$Value1 <- ave(d$Value1, d$ID, d$Type, FUN=sum)
d$Value2 <- ave(d$Value2, d$ID, d$Type, FUN=sum)
dResult <- d[d$Flag==1,]
dResult
# > dResult
#   ID   Type Flag Value1 Value2       Result
# 2  1  Apple    1  29313  30835 3.243068e-05
# 3  1 Orange    1   2222   3423 0.000000e+00
# 4  2 Orange    1  24566  32234 0.000000e+00
```

For having the `$Result` in [%] you can do `d$Result <- 100*ave(...)`

Comment: Hey Thanks ! But Value 2 in the first row should be 30835 !

Answer (score 1):

Convert the data.frame to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'ID', 'Type', if the number of observations is greater than 1, do the division as showed in the OP's post or else return 0.  Remove the 'Flag' column, Then get the `sum` of 'Value1' and 'Value2' grouped by 'ID' and 'Type' and take the `unique`

```
library(data.table)
 setDT(df1)[, Result := if(.N >1) round(100*Value1[1]/(Value2[1]+Value2[2]), 3) 
                                       else 0, .(ID, Type)]
df2 <- df1[, -3, with = FALSE]
df2[, (3:4) := lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols = Value1:Value2, .(ID, Type)]
unique(df2)
#   ID   Type Value1 Value2 Result
#1:  1  Apple  29313  30835  0.003
#2:  1 Orange   2222   3423  0.000
#3:  2 Orange  24566  32234  0.000
```

---

Or we can use the `tidyverse` in a single flow.  After grouping by 'ID', 'Type', create the 'Result' column, followed by getting the `sum` of 'Value`columns with`mutate_at`, remove the 'Flag' and get the`distinct` rows

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID, Type) %>% 
    mutate(Result = round(100*if(n()==2) first(Value1)/(first(Value2)+last(Value2))
                             else 0, 3)) %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(matches('Value')), sum) %>% 
    select(-Flag) %>% 
    distinct
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   ID, Type [3]
#      ID   Type Value1 Value2 Result
#    <int>  <chr>  <int>  <int>  <dbl>
#1     1  Apple  29313  30835  0.003
#2     1 Orange   2222   3423  0.000
#3     2 Orange  24566  32234  0.000
```